# How to improve bluetooth audio quality

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio

- OS: Android 10
- Device: Samsung Galaxy 10e
- Speakers: Marley Get Togeather

I bought some new bluetooth speakers that were rated highly for audio quality, but when I connect my phone, it sounds really poor.  If I use a cable, it's fine, but bluetooth is really bad.  How can I improve audio quality?  I read somewhere that all speakers for this brand support AAC, but I can't seem to get that working.

---

If I long-hold the bluetooth button in the drop-down, and select the gear beside the device, I don't see any options.

[image]

If I enable developer options and look at the bluetooth settings I see:

- codec: SBC
- sample rate: 44.1 kHz
- bits/sample: 16

[image]

If I try to change the code, sample-rate, or bits/sample in the developer options, it instantly reverts to the original settings.  By that I mean if I select AAC, I hear no difference, but the menu shows AAC until I switch windows and then switch back.  At that point it will show SBC again so I suspect it never actually change and that was a GUI bug.

I haven't used bluetooth much, so I don't know if I have a problem with my configuration, a problem with what I'm doing, or if the device itself is limited.

Comment: Re:changing properties in developer settings, the Bluetooth needs to be *on* and speakers connected

Comment: I noticed that.  If I am disconnected, the settings don't change at all.  If I am connected, the settings appear to change, but if I refresh the menu (exit and come back), the settings go back to default.  I don't hear any difference in sound, so I suspect the settings only appeared to change (they didn't actually change).

Comment: In that case, it looks like a bug with device. Try reaching out to Samsung